# How to delete a downloaded voice from Siri in iPhone5s

Tags: iphone, siri

I would like to delete a Siri voice that has taken up most of the remaining small space that i had left in my iPhone 5s. Can anyone please tell me how i should go about deleting the downloaded voice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **Settings** > **General** > **Accessibility** > **VoiceOver** > **Speech** and select the language.

Then tap on **Edit**, swipe on the **language** and select **Remove**.

[image]

Comment: Does this still work on iOS 14.6?